# Accessing User information in .Net8 routes

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I have a route that I need to access the current user information. I am using JWT and able to login and store certain information in. But when I need to grab the that information from another route, the user comes back null and isAuthenticated says false. Which doesn't make full sense to me as why.  The information i need to grab out is the ChurchId. I have a One-to-Many relationship with users and church and a one-to-many relationship with church and members. The route I am having trouble with is getting all the members from the specific church base on the current user logged in. The frontend is in React, and I read some things on doing the filter from the frontend, when I tried those suggestion as well I didn't get the results I needed. But part of me tells me that doing it in the backend route is best practice. So I would like to figure it out from the .NET side of things.

Login route

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginModel login)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var existing_user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(login.UserName);
            if(existing_user == null)
                    return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
                        {
                            Status = "Failed",
                            Result = false,
                            Message = "Please Create a user",
                            Errors = new List<string>()
                            {
                                "User doesn't exist"
                            }
                        });
            var result = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(existing_user, login.Password);
            if (result)
                {
                    existing_user.LastLoggedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(existing_user);

                    // Log the successful login with ChurchId
                    _logger.LogInformation("User {UserName} successfully logged in with ChurchId {ChurchId}.", existing_user.UserName, existing_user.ChurchId);

                    var jwtToken = GenerateJwtToken(existing_user);

                    // Return a successful response with the JWT token
                    return Ok(new AuthResult()
                    {
                        Token = jwtToken,
                        Result = true,
                        Status = "Success",
                        Message ="Login was Successful;"
                    });
                    
                }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
            {
                Status = "Failed",
                            Result = false,
                            Message = "Login was unsuccessful",
                            Errors = new List<string>()
                            {
                                "Invalid Login Attempt"
                            }
            });
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

allMembers route

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("allMembers")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllMembers()
{

    // Inspect HttpContext.User for debugging
    var user = HttpContext.User;
    var token = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
    _logger.LogInformation($"Received token: {token}");

    if (user != null)

    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"User Information - Name: {user.Identity.Name}, IsAuthenticated: {user.Identity.IsAuthenticated}");

        // Log all claims for debugging
        foreach (var claim in user.Claims)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Claim Type: {claim.Type}, Claim Value: {claim.Value}");
        }

        // Check if ChurchId claim exists and is not null or empty
        var churchIdClaim = user.FindFirst("ChurchId");
        if (churchIdClaim == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(churchIdClaim.Value))
        {
            // Log the issue for debugging
            _logger.LogError("Invalid or missing ChurchId claim. User: {UserName}");

            // Handle the case where ChurchId is null or empty
            // You might want to return an error or handle this case as needed
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Invalid or missing ChurchId claim." });
        }

        // Use the extracted ChurchId directly in your service method
        var currentUserChurchId = churchIdClaim.Value;

        try
        {
            // Now you can use currentUserChurchId in your service method
            var members = await _memberService.GetMembersAsync(currentUserChurchId);

            return Ok(members);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error retrieving members for ChurchId {ChurchId}. User: {UserName}", currentUserChurchId, user.Identity.Name);
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Log an error or handle the case where the user object is null
        _logger.LogError("HttpContext.User is null.");
        return BadRequest(new { message = "Invalid or missing user information." });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `[Authorize]` attribute before your GetAllMembers().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JWT bearer authentication enabled, API endpoints can be protected by applying the `[Authorize]` attribute to the corresponding controller or action. This ensures that only requests with valid and authenticated JWTs are allowed access to the protected resources.

The `[Authorize]` attribute is a powerful tool for enforcing access control in ASP.NET Core. When applied to a controller or action, it triggers the framework's authorization process, which verifies whether the current user is authenticated and has the necessary permissions to access the requested resource.

Try to add `[Authorize]` attribute before your GetAllMembers().

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Route("allMembers")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllMembers()
{

    // Inspect HttpContext.User for debugging
    var user = HttpContext.User;
...
 }
```